# jquery select div inside parent of calling element

Tags: jquery, selector

For the past several hours i am trying to set the display of a hidden div to visible but i can't reach that div with jquery.

After clicking the button i pass the value to a function. 
from there i want to set a hidden div visible which is inside one of the divs of parent. but i can't reach that div.

I have tried parent(), closest(), find() and several other things but failed to reach that div.

Here is the code what i have done so far [jsfedle](http://goo.gl/y7jNH1)

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't use a URL shortener to circumvent the JSFiddle link restriction. Your code should be in the question so that if any 3rd party sites go down your question is still answerable.

Comment: Or to put it more bluntly: The site told you you couldn't do that ***for a reason***. So rather than bypassing the check, actually look at why it said that, take the [tour], read the [help], etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your onclick event does not have element context as you have not passed it as an argument. due to which `this` does not exist in click function created by you.

You can rather use jquery to attach the event:

```
$('.product-select').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find( ".product-selected" ).show();
});
```

### Working Demo

Comment: I was also passing a parameter with onclick, if i don't use onclick how do i pass the parameter?

Comment: like this `selectProduct(this)`

Answer (score 0):

`parent()` will take you to the parent and then inside it to find `.product-selected` use `.find()`

```
$('.product-select').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".product-selected").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

.closest() goes UP the DOM, I guess you need .find()...